# Allow the user to save the documents From iOS Mail App to my Application

Tags: ios, ios4, save, email, email-attachments

I need to show/allow the user directly to save the mail attachments in to my application and allow them to view for later purpose like Dropbox.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the "open in" feature.  By modifying the plist.  There is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app) on this.